# Message persistence - Redis pub/sub

Tags: java, redis

A message published on a channel is received by subscribers at the other end.  However, if no active subscriber is found the message is simply lost.

And here is my question, is it possible to modify Redis to support message persistence when subscriber is no active?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't - messages are sent to all subscribers (if there are any) as they are published, and are not persistable.